# Flutter 2.0x 3.0x image not call

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image

[image]

In my flutter project, I registered the image as a picture.

To use images by resolution

I created a 2.0x or 3.0x folder, but

What should I do?

pubspec.yaml is input as shown in the image below.

[image]

please help me!

I tried repare pubspec.yaml file.

assets/images/

to

- assets/images/onboard/
- assets/images/splash/
- assets/images/2.0x/
- assets/images/2.0x/onboard/
- assets/images/2.0x/splash/
- assets/images/3.0x/
- assets/images/3.0x/onboard/
- assets/images/3.0x/splash/

In more deail

The image is called like this.
Image. asset(
'assets/images/onboard/ic_tuto_01.png',
width: width
)

And I set the screen resolution to 2960 X 1400 on the Android device, but
Images in the 2.0x or 3.0x folder are not output and
Only the images in the /assets/images root are loaded continuously.

I don't think it's compatible with resolution.

What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. How do you actually display the images? Please include some code.

Comment: what is the problem here? What errors have you been through?

Comment: Dear doneforaiur, Nguyen family!  I added more information in my case.  please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Self Answer.

[show shape of folder image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmWKV.png)

folder edited like picture.

and

pubspec.ymal edited like this

[show pubspec.yaml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8v3KH.png)

2.0x and 3.0x is work!